# Who was the first to invent the induction motor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I have heard that Galileo Ferraris and Nikola Tesla invented the induction motor independently.  Does anyone know who was the first and were they similar in power output and design?   This may be a duplicate question but the search does not seem to come up with anything for me. I am also interested in knowing why two people are credited with the same discovery if they worked independently. (Unless of course they both did it at the exact moment.:-))

Comment: Hi, welcome to hsm. We try to avoid having questions here answers to which can be found by googling and/or by looking up [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_motor#History). If several people do something independently and the time lapse is not too long it makes little difference who did it chronologically first, so often all are credited. Like Newton and Leibniz for calculus.

Comment: Have you read Wikipedia article on "induction motor"?